# Scriptlab custom function getting TypeError: Network request failed when making GET api calls

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel, scriptlab

```
/**
 * Get Volume .
 * @customfunction
 * @param {string} companyId
 * @param {string} date
 */
async function getVolume(companyId, date) {
  //You can change this URL to any web request you want to work with.
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append(
    "Authorization",
    "Bearer token_value"
  );
  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders
  };

  const url = `url value`;
  const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  console.log(response);
  //Expect that status code is in 200-299 range
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();
  return jsonResponse;
}
```

when i make the request using postman it works but errors out in excel scriptlab. Please can anyone guide me to the fix to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you please let us know the url? This looks like it may be a CORS failure.

Comment: The fetch api works in custom functions with ScriptLab. You may can refer to the section "Create a custom function that requests data from the web" of [Tutorial: Create custom functions in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows) for the usage of fetch in Custom Functions.

Comment: CORS was removed on the server, also followed the tutorial. did not work out.